# Macro definition for message mapping

Tags: c++, macros

Formerly I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863158/message-map-in-win32-no-mfc) and got a fair response. But I am stucked with below macro definitions.

The below definitions generates a Message Map function like it is in MFC Message Map. But the code below does not compile.

Whole statements starting with `this->` are problematic ones except the one in MSG_HANDLER `this->meth(msg);` dont know why..

Hence what can be done to correct this issue?

I use VS 2008.

```
#define MSG_UNPACK(var, id, msg) x##id *var = (x##id *)(msg);

#define BEGIN_MSG_MAP                          \
   protected:                                  \
   virtual void dispatchToMsgMap(xMessage *msg)\
   {                                           \
     if (msg->msg.message == WM_NULL)          \
     {                                         \
       return;                                 \
     }

#define MSG_HANDLER(meth, wm_msg)              \
     else if (msg->msg.message == wm_msg)      \
     {                                         \
       this->meth(msg);                        \
       return;                                 \
     }

#define END_MSG_MAP(base)                      \
     else if (msg->msg.message == WM_COMMAND)  \
     {                                         \                       
       this->dispatchToCmdMap(msg);            \                       
       return;                                 \                       
     }                                         \                       
     else if (msg->msg.message == WM_NOTIFY)   \                       
     {                                         \                       
       this->dispatchToNotifyMap(msg);         \                       
       return;                                 \                       
     }                                         \                       
                                               \                       
     base::dispatchToMsgMap(msg);              \                       
   };

#define BEGIN_CMD_MAP                          \
   virtual void dispatchToCmdMap(xMessage *msg)\
   {                                           \                              
     MSG_UNPACK(Cmd, WM_COMMAND, msg);         \                              
                                               \                              
     if (Cmd->ItemID == 0)                     \                              
     {                                         \                              
        /* not allowed */                      \                              
     }                                                                        

#define CMD_HANDLER(meth, cmd_id)              \
     else if (Cmd->ItemID == cmd_id)           \
     {                                         \                                
       this->meth(Cmd->ItemID);                \                                
     }                                                                          

#define END_CMD_MAP(base)                      \
     else                                      \                              
     {                                         \                              
       base::dispatchToCmdMap(msg);        \                              
     }                                         \                              
   };
```

Here, for example `this->dispatchToCmdMap(msg);            \`  is 41st line.

1>d:\devel\coding\vs2008\test2\test2\messagemapper.h(41) : error C2059: syntax error : 'this'
1>d:\devel\coding\vs2008\test2\test2\messagemapper.h(41) : error C2017: illegal escape sequence
1>d:\devel\coding\vs2008\test2\test2\messagemapper.h(42) : error C2059: syntax error : 'return'
1>d:\devel\coding\vs2008\test2\test2\messagemapper.h(42) : error C2017: illegal escape sequence
1>d:\devel\coding\vs2008\test2\test2\messagemapper.h(43) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'
1>d:\devel\coding\vs2008\test2\test2\messagemapper.h(43) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
1>d:\devel\coding\vs2008\test2\test2\messagemapper.h(43) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'

Comment: A function shouldn't end with ";".  Have you tried it without the ";"?  It stops my mind from investigating further.  It could be that it prevents dispatchToCmdMap to be defined, so it can't be accessed.

Comment: @stefaanv; tried but no success
@Timbo; added error messages

Comment: @stefaanv; sorry this is inline function defined in header file so it must be ended with ";" I forgot this situation.

Comment: @whoi - inline functions in headers do not have to be ended in ";" - it's entriely superfluous.

Comment: @Joe Gauterin - ok no problem, but still got errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "illegal escape sequence" part tells me that you have traling whitespace after your `\`. Therefore the next lines are not part of the macro.

Answer (score 1):

First, check that you haven't got whitespace after the slashes at the the end of the lines.

If that doesn't help then you should look at the pre-processed output to see what is actually being compiled (and post that here if you need to).

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove spaces after "\". This symbol should be the last in the line.